# htaccess rewrite url and navigate to specified page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have disabled .php extension from all the pages of my website using htaccess. Now my website can be navigated as

1. www.domainname.com/page1
2. www.domainname.com/page2
3. www.domainname.com/page3...

Now out of all the pages in website, for some pages I need to add prefix in the URL like

1. www.domainname.com/**mypages**/page5
2. www.domainname.com/**mypages**/page6

How can I do that using htaccess and without creating subdirectory named "mypages"?

Comment: Can you show your existing .htaccess by editing the question.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

## some pages need to have mypages/
RewriteRule ^mypages/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]

## for rest internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```